# Changing Express constant based on URL (ie localhost vs production)

Tags: node.js, express

I'm fairly new to node and express...

I have a constant I set in my Node/Express application for "Domain". I'm constantly switching between localhost and the actual url when I switch between development and production.

I'm trying to figure out how I can automatically test the URL so that when the code is read on the server (ie actual domain url vs localhost) that it sets the proper domain url.

Here is my code:

```
function define(name, value) {
    Object.defineProperty(exports, name, {
        value:      value,
        enumerable: true
    });
}


define("DOMAIN", "http://www.actual_domain.com");
// define("DOMAIN", "http://localhost:3000");
```

Anyone have a simple solution for this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is many solutions for this, but usually this is done by environment variables, depends on your platform, but, in Linux systems, you do the following in your shell

```
export ENV_URL="http://www.example.com"
```

and to make sure its exported successfully

```
echo $ENV_URL
```

and in your code you do

```
const base_url = process.env.ENV_URL || "http://www.default.com";
```

in your local machine you set the ENV_URL to localhost or whatever you prefer, and in your server you set it to your actual URL.

or you could simply have many configuration files and you can determine the appropriate one by the environemnt variable like

```
export ENV=PROD
```

and in your code you can load the prod configuration file that contains your environment configurations.

Answer (score 0):

The de facto way to do this sort of thing is through environment variables. Have a look at 12factor.net for a load of best practices, but in general you want to put differences in the environment into environment variables, then read those variables at runtime.